# How can I define Slot Priority for Slot Values in an Intent in LexV2

Tags: amazon-lex

I am trying to build my Lex Bot but receiving this error message

Details Recommended action Slot ids [NumberTwo, Number] don't define a slot priority. Update the intent to add a priority to these slots. - Slot ids [Number] don't define a slot priority. Update the intent to add a priority to these slots. - Slot ids [Answer] don't define a slot priority. Update the intent to add a priority to these slots. - Slot ids [Number] don't define a slot priority. Update the intent to add a priority to these slots. -

I am using AWS SDK for Lex with Python to create the bot.

How can I update the intent to add slot priority for my slots?

Comment: Are you using the right tag? (see tag description)

Comment: I am not using any tags to my knowledge. Can you please provide docs?

Comment: You are using tag "lex" in your question above. That tag is described as "Lex is a computer program that generates lexical analyzers ("scanners" or "lexers"). Lex is commonly used with the yacc parser generator. For questions about Amazon Lex, use the tag amazon-lex instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here https://repost.aws/questions/QUB4WaCne6QxOntq1-R6LtlQ/how-can-i-define-slot-priority-for-slot-values-in-an-intent-in-lex-v-2

The python AWS Lex v2 SDK method I used to add slot priorities to and Intent slot were:

1. create_intent
2. create_slot
3. update_intent